# How to search multiple file types from Windows Explorer search box?

Tags: windows-explorer, search

I would like to use the Windows Explorer Search box to search for multiple file types.

Is there any supported syntax to do so?

I tried:

```
*.docx *.xlsx
*.docx, *.xlsx
*.docx; *.xlsx
*.docx or *.xlsx
*.docx | *.xlsx
```

But none of this works (while `*.docx` or `*.xlsx` alone works)

Comment: Better alternative to Windows Explorer Search box. Use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/)

Comment: thx @AEonAX, I'll take a look

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Enter it like this

`*.txt OR *.PDF OR *.xls`

Keep OR capital letters

Comment: Why "OR" ? This is the most non-standard thing I could think about...

Comment: @androiddeveloper You asked why someone would use the word `OR` inside a search expression, such as `*.ppt OR *.odp`. The English word "**OR**" is similar, but not the same, as the word "**OR**" in Mathematics and Computer Science.  The search expression has different syntax, but identical semmantics, to the following :  "search for files ***X*** such that file ***X*** has a name ending in `.ppt` or a name ending in `.odp`". The name of the file could end in `.ppt` or the name of the file could end in `.odp`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use wildcards (*, ?) in the search box as follows.

```
EXT: .txt OR .pdf OR .xls OR .doc*
```

Comment: Is it not necessary to use parens `ext:( ... )`?